# What measures of centrality exist for fully connected networks with weighted directed edges?

Tags: graph-theory, network-flow, network

I have a network of cities with transport links between them. The transport links are not symmetric in both directions, therefore asymmetric edges between nodes. There is a variable number quantifying the transport capacity and average flow during times of the day. In my dataset, there are edges between every city/town.

What measures exist to quantify a particular nodes influence in this network other than simply summation of the edge values?

Comment: By "fully connected" do you mean [strongly connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component)? Or do you mean that the underlying digraph is [complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph)?

Comment: @mhum, `complete`

Comment: In that case, if your distance function follows the triangle inequality, then I'm not sure you can do much better than average edge weight (although, you could conceivably have two such averages per node, one for out-going and one for in-coming edges). If your distance function doesn't follow the triangle inequality, you might be able to use [betweenness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betweenness_centrality) as another measure.